# Youtube data api "Operation timed out"

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

We are having youtube content manager account and using youtube data api to upload videos from our application. Till 13 Nov 15, everything was working fine but from last two days, some video are not getting uploaded with an exception stating 
"Caught Google service Exception 28 message is Operation timed out after 100001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"

Whereas sometime even 20 minutes long videos are uploaded successfully.

What may the possible reason of such a breakdown.

Comment: What happens if you catch these failures and retry the upload?

Comment: Sometimes its uploaded without any issue, but most of the time it says "Operation timed out".

Comment: The script is timing out after 100 seconds. Have you adjusted all the necessary server-side timeout settings? Does it only happen on larger uploads?

Comment: Yes, i have increased the curl timeout to 200 seconds. The problem occurs randomly, sometimes timeout occurs even for smaller videos and sometime a video of length more than 20 minutes get uploaded.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the youtube API changed in some way? APIs change from time to time. Requiring a new format or additional parameters/data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I contacted Youtube but did not get a response from them, I also check for API changes but no luck at all.

Comment: Hmmm.. it could be a connectivity issue. You could try analysing the connection with the server where it's uploaded to on the device the youtube data api is running maybe it's a connectivity problem.

Comment: Actually its a cron job, which picks local video files residing on the server and upload it to you tube. So the connection is established between server and youtube api.

Comment: The API has not changed in a way that would cause these errors.

Comment: Yeah its more likely a connectivity thing.